# iso movie for watching on TV

Tags: iso-image, tv, blu-ray

I've downloaded movie which is in .ISO extension file.
When I open it using Deamon Tools I can see three folsers:
Any!,BDMV,CERTIFICATE.

Is it possible to place this movie on portable HDD to watch it on TV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BDMV is the actual video.  It is a BluRay formatted video.  As it is a .ISO file, I am GUESSING that it is still encrypted.  What you need to do is find an information on transcoding the video to another format, such as http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/333774-Create-MKV-from-a-BDMV-folder

That will allow you to get the video into a more open format.

This answer is intentionally vague as to decryption since that is getting close to DMCA areas.